# Testing Environment-sensitive code in Lithium

Tags: unit-testing, lithium

In a test, is there a way to temporarily override what `Environment::get()` returns in a class that extends `StaticObject`?

I'm writing a [feature toggle](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html) plugin for Lithium. I want to test switching features on and off based on the environment. For example, the feature `new_ui` should be on in staging but off in production.

In my test I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Features::add('new_ui', array('production' => false, 'staging' => true));
// Magic that makes Environment::get() in the Features class return 'staging'
$this->assertTrue(Feature::check('new_ui'));
// Magic that makes Environment::get() in the Features class return 'production'
$this->assertFalse(Feature::check('new_ui'));
```

I could probably hack something together using a `MockEnvironment` but is there a more pure Lithium way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing a test, mocks would be the correct way to go, or else an injectable closure that's used to return the environment state.

Comment: I ended up mocking both Environment and my Features class. Any other feedback much appreciated, https://github.com/michaeltwofish/li3_features

Comment: Looks good. I would also consider including a helper to keep templates a little cleaner.